# Combining sub-sub data with parent data in Excel or R?

Tags: r, excel

I'm incredibly unsure what to call this problem, I feel like there might be a compsci term for it but I'm not familiar with it.

As a trivial example, let's say I have a simple example of parent company and subcompanies identified by unique numbers. What I want, is if Company A owns Company B, and Company B owns Company C, I want my data to reflect that Company A owns Company C. Here's a trivial example

What I would like to do is transform this data:

```
 Parent Sub 
 133    922 
 199    633 
 210    677 
 633    792
```

To This Data where it takes sub-sub company 792 and assigns it to company 199 as well.

```
 Parent Sub 
 133    922 
 199    633 
 210    677 
 199    792
```

I feel like I could brute force this with VBA where it just does a search for every subcompany to see if it has a subcompany in turn repetitively, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter pre-built way of doing it already in excel somehow.

Also willing to transfer the data to R and try something there if if there's an easier solution in R.

Comment: Transitive property. That's all I got.

Comment: I think R can deal with this as a graph object, like in the package *igraph* - I'll see if I can cook something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with a join (or `merge`), to add the sub-sub-company in a third column, then you just need to take the rows and append them to the original data frame.

```
df <- read.table(text = "Parent Sub 
133    922 
199    633 
210    677 
633    792", header=TRUE)

left_join(df,df,
          by=c("Sub"="Parent")) %>%
  select(Parent, Sub = Sub.y) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sub)) %>%
  bind_rows(df)

#  Parent Sub
#1    199 792
#2    133 922
#3    199 633
#4    210 677
#5    633 792
```

**EDIT**:
I hadn't noticed that in your example you actually replace the existing row. That's not a problem, we just need to look for Parents that are also Subs, instead of looking for Subs that are also Parents:

```
left_join(df,df,
          by=c("Parent"="Sub")) %>%
  mutate(Parent = if_else(is.na(Parent.y), Parent, Parent.y)) %>%
  select(-Parent.y)

#  Parent Sub
#1    133 922
#2    199 633
#3    210 677
#4    199 792
```

**EDIT 2**: An Excel equivalent to this second approach could be that one. Suppose you put your data in A2:B5 (the headers in A1:A2). Then, you can enter this in C2:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(1+MATCH(A2,B$2:B$5,0)))
```

So now column C will contain the hyper-Parent company if the Parent company was in the Sub column.

[image: Excel snapshot]

Then you just need a step to replace column A when column C is non-NA (something like `=IFNA(C2,A2)`)

**For method 1**, I don't know how to do that in Excel, since we need to add rows to an existing data table (or bind two tables). If we're willing to do that manually, then again put your data in A2:B5, and in D2 use this:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,B$2:B$5,A$2:A$5)
```

In E2 use that:

```
=IF(D2="#N/A","",B2)
```

[image: Excel snapshot for adding rows]

So here the logic was that we find Parents that are also Subs, and we can just get their sub-Sub. In Excel, you would need to find a way to get rid of the #N/A and assemble the data in A:B with the one in D:E, not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: I appreciate the response, deleting the original isn't strictly necessarily I should formatted my question better. I'll try this method out in R, I didn't even know this was a thing, One quick question, will this method work for a 4th level? Like if company 792 owned company 793, does this method keep going? I don't quite understand how your code works just looking at it here, hopefully once i try it out here in a few minutes I'll have a better sense.

Comment: It can be generalized, but it requires making an additional join. The basic idea is that a join (or the base function `merge`) can match two data frames on an "index" column, and assemble the entries that have the same index. Here the trick I use is to join the data frame on itself, so I keep the columns 1 and 2 intact, and add a third column which is only the entries of column 2 that had a match in column 1. I'm posting an Excel equivalent to approach 2, that might help.

Comment: An excel equivalent would be incredible! I'm much more comfortable with Excel instead of R since I can see the numbers in a way I feel I can't with R.

Comment: Edited my answer, see if you can use that. I'm not familiar enough with Excel to really finalize these methods though.

Comment: Trying out your join method, I believe it's working, it's hard to verify because my 250k columns just jumped to 750k on the first iteration ha. Can I ask what the %>% does? I've seen it before in R sytnax and I thought it was a function without any assigned function? How are you using it here? I see it twice and I'm not sure I totally understand

Comment: Also if I copy your exact code I'm getting this error: Error: Column name `Sub` must not be duplicated.Use .name_repair to specify repair. Removing the %>% after the "suffx = c("del", "") seems to fix it.

Comment: Oh right. Indeed, `%xx%` is a format to define your own operators, but several of them are already used in R. In particular, `%>%` is a 'pipe', similar to `|` on UNIX systems. It takes the result of one operation and forwards it to the next. So `f(g(x))` means `x %>% g %>% f`, just much easier to read. It is made broadly available by the `tidyverse`, a set of packages (including `dplyr` that I used here and others) that make standard operations a lot easier. But it will soon be also included in base R. So my code can be read as "join `df` with `df`, then filter it, then bind it with `df`".

Comment: This problem might be due to the `suffix` part, I edited my answer to avoid using it. It's slightly strange, we may not have the same version of `dplyr`.

Comment: Gotcha thank you, I've read a few descriptions of the pipe before but never quite got it. Your f(g(x)) makes a lot more sense! Although the fact that the R syntax goes instead out instead of outside-in might take a bit to get used to, ha. Thanks so much. I'm trying out both ways, your excel method makes a lot of sense as well, at this point it's becoming a computational power issue just due to the sheer size. Oh well, I'll truck through it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is ludicrously complicated, but I think it works. There is probably a smarter way to extract hierarchical data using R's *igraph* package, but hopefully somebody will be along to point out what I can simplify.

```
library(igraph)

dat <- read.table(text="Parent Sub 
 133    922 
 199    633 
 210    677 
 633    792
 211    133", header=TRUE)

# if <- represents ownership, we have:
# 211 <- 133 <- 922
# 199 <- 633 <- 792
# 210 <- 677
```

Create a graph object that stores the relationships between each `Parent` and `Sub` row. See `plot(g)` to get a better idea of what this outputs.

```
g     <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)
```

`components`, finds which values belong in groups, or 'connected components' in the *igraph* lingo.

```
cmp   <- components(g)
```

`degree` is used to identify how many out-going and in-coming connections relate to each value. In this case, I'm particularly interested in those root values which don't have a parent.

```
dg    <- degree(g, mode="in")
roots <- names(cmp$membership) %in% names(dg)[dg == 0]
```

And finally, this is just a bunch of matching up so that each `Sub` value is related to the root value in each group.

```
dat$Parent <- names(cmp$membership[roots])[
 match(
   cmp$membership[match(dat$Sub, names(cmp$membership))],
   cmp$membership[roots]
  )
]
dat

#  Parent Sub
#1    211 922
#2    199 633
#3    210 677
#4    199 792
#5    211 133
```

Results look okay.

Comment: Checking it out, are you able to give a brief overview of what's going on here? I've never used this package, I copied your code and just ran it on my original dataset, and I'm looking it over right now

Comment: @MSCRN - i'll try. I'm not sure I exactly know what I'm doing myself! :-D

Comment: @MSCRN - logic added now.

Comment: Haha it's totally ok, don't worry about it. I appreciate the response I'll try and decode it with a simple example and figure it out, I appreciate the response!